# event.target doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
function imgU() {

  if (event.target.type == "select-one") {
    iSize = event.target.value;
  } else if (event.target.type == "text") {
    iText = event.target.value;
  } else if (event.target.id == "imc") {
    var nColor = event.target.value;
    iColor = nColor.replace("#", "");
  } else if (event.target.id == "tmc") {
    var mColor = event.target.value;
    tColor = mColor.replace("#", "");
  }

  var imsrc = "http://via.placeholder.com/" + iSize + "/" + iColor + "/" + tColor + "?text=" + iText;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.  I get the error event is not defined. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you calling `imgU`?

Comment: You never call that function or define `event`. Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin, I'm assuming that's happening somewhere because apparently it works fine in Chrome...

Comment: function imgU(event) should do the trick

Comment: You can Pass event variable in function `imgU( event )`

Comment: @Andy — My point is that the question fails to demonstrate it, so we can't reproduce it.

Comment: function imgU(event) should work

Comment: @ThomasKleßen — Depends on how `imgU` is being called, which the question fails to show us.

Comment: @PunitPatel — The function declaration doesn't expect any arguments, and you need to have a value to pass to it in the first place.

Comment: @Niladri — Depends on how `imgU` is being called, which the question fails to show us.

Comment: @Quentin You are right. i assume this function is called as eventListener. And most probably i am right if it works in Chrome ;)

Comment: @ThomasKleßen — I was assuming it was called with `<button onclick="imgU()">`. This is why the OP needs to provide a [mcve].

Comment: thak you all. the code form is thsi one:

Comment: <form>
 <select onchange="imgU(event)">
  <option value=""> Select </option>
  <option value="150x50">Small</option>
  <option value="350x50">Medium</option>
  <option value="750x50">Large</option>
 </select><br><br>


Add text
<input type="text" name="" onchange="imgU(event)">
<br><br>
Select Color:
<input type="color" name="" onchange="imgU(event)" id="imc">
<br><br>
Text Color: <input type="color" name="" onchange="imgU(event)" id="tmc">
<br><br>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/000000/fff?text=Image1" id="myImage">
</form>

Comment: i put event as argument and it works :)